# How to unnittest GUI tkinter in docker (CI)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, unit-testing, tkinter

I am working with a project that uses the tkinter python GUI library and I would really like to test the UI in a CI pipeline but it seems that tkinter doesn't like virtual environments and needs a screen.

This is what I get when I try running tkinter in a docker:

```
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I tried this with a very basic testing script:

```py
import unittest
import tkinter as tk

class TestTk(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Test Tk")
        self.root.geometry("300x200")

    def test_title(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.root.title(), "Test Tk")

    def test_geometry(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.root.geometry(), "300x200")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    unittest.main()
```

Does anyone know the proper way to test tkinter or if there is a way to trick it into thinking there is a screen ?

Comment: It's unspecific. See [ask]. Research more and choose one method. Anyway, I recommend ```Xvfb```.